Circuit works only when oscilloscope probe is connected and does not work otherwise
I have built the circuit shown below.
The problem is that the circuit only works when I connect oscilloscope probes between node-A and the ground.
If I remove or decouple the probe-ground from the circuit ground then circuit does not work. I have ensured that all grounds are intact.
IC U5 is a TL082 op-amp being used as a differential amplifier. U6 is LM393 op-amp comparator circuit being used as a zero crossing detector.
Do I need to use a decoupling capacitor? I think I do not need a decoupling capacitor because the circuit starts working as it should the moment I connect the probe-ground wire to the circuit ground.
Any clue what mistake I am making?

After the first 5 comments, I am updating the circuit as follows. The components in red show my understanding after comments.


Can you please explain, what the function of R10, R11, D1 and Q1 is? I assume, the circuit will work if you remove them all and directly connect the ATmega input to R9/U6.

R10, R11, D1 and Q1 are making the zero-crossing detector that invert as needed. D1 is bakers clamp (just to speed up)

i will remove R11

There's not a single supply bypass capacitor in the circuit. Also is the output of a TTL 74LS14 compatible with AVR CMOS input?

Component values would be rather helpful.

All parts need to be labeled with value or model number. U6 looks like a comparator - what would you need the whole mess after it for?

Yes U6 is a comparator. I will add a supply bypass capacitor ( i am thinking to use 0.1uF Cap). But i still cant figure out what the oscilloscope ground probe does when i connect it to the ground of circuit that makes U5 to perform differential amplification as is supposed to do. Circuit is already grounded.

So much so that just by connecting the probe-ground clip to the circuit ground without even connecting probe-measuring clip to Node-A, makes the circuit work and U5 output produces differential output of (LC-Tank-1  minus LC-Tank-2)

small update: U5 output produces differential output of (LC-Tank-1 minus LC-Tank-2)*gain

circuit is running off 5V only? If U6 is a comparator, and it's - input is at 0V, I would expect it to be always on. This doesn't make sense to me.

"Do I need to use a decoupling capacitor?" You need several. Please post oscillograms of your PWM generation and Vgs for your main MOSFETs.

what are values of R4, 5, 6, 7? If you have gain in this stage it could very well be oscillating until you connect the probe. You may need small caps across R6 and R7 to roll off the gain.

Also - how about telling us a few contextual details like - what is the actual purpose of the circuit? what are you trying to do? What frequency is it running at?

LC-Tank-1 and LC-Tank-2 are two inputs from main circuit that are being fed to differential amplifier (U5). The differential amplifier output is the difference between (LC-Tank-1 and LC-Tank-2 ) multiplied by a gain (=R6/R5) . U6 is a comparator circuit, I am trying to detect zero-crossing of voltage across circuit (L1, R1 and C1)

@winny, how will decoupling capacitor connected across Vcc and GND aid in resolving this issue, i am trying figure out my mistake or deficiency as i cant figure out what the oscilloscope probe-ground clip does when it is connected it to the ground of circuit that makes U5 to perform differential amplification as is supposed to do...i want to understand what o'scope ground clip is doing that i could not have provided that makes  DA opamp circuit work?

I can't say it will, but decoupling capacitors is usually a must. Follow best design practices. You may have several issues going on at once and you need to address them one by one.

Yes i anticipate that there might be several issues. In my updated circuit, by connecting RX and RY as shown, will it help is making the circuit work without o'scope probes? Thanks.

You are asking about step 40. You need to go back to step one, read datasheets, simulate, follow application notes (decoupling capacitors, layout).
